# How to check kanji and add furigana automatically

Tags: php, html, unicode, localization

As title, I wonder if there is a convenient way to get the hiragana text from kanji, then insert it automatically above the kanji (like furigana)

For example, my database:

```
1   |      私はA-sanです。
```

I want to show the text on website as:

[image]

I am coding php and here is how I think

```
function modify_text($text) {
   foreach ($word in text){
         if ($word is kanji){
            //find hiragana
            //do html to convert text to furigana
      {
   }
}
```

I think with html ruby element, it is not hard to insert the text above kanji. However, I am not sure if there are libraries that can detect kanji words to find its hiragana.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every characters and symbols are in [unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) and you can grab them by using `preg_replace`.

it's that code you need.

```
<?php
//you can replace $text with your own content.
$text = '私はA-sanです。';
$hiragana  = preg_replace('/[^\x{3041}-\x{3096}]+/u', ' ', $text);
echo '<sup>'.$hiragana.'</sup>'.$text;
```

Comment: Thank you. However, do you know if it is possible to find hiragana translation of kanji word ?

Comment: @emiya hiragana unicode ranges are x3041 - x3096 and I grab them first